# c# File.ReadLines doesnt work right

Tags: c#, readfile, readline

I have a txt file and readline is not working right for my file.

My lines in my code.

[image: open picture]

And this is my text in my file.Lines are like this, but my code doesnt understand lines like this.

```
X02233    52330 DISCHY 8 BLUZ
    std STD     0       0       0       0       0               8698230653909   0.00    
X02237    52337 VALONIA BLUZ  STD STD     0       0       0       0       0               8698230653916   0.00 
X02245    72458 HARMONY 9 BLUZ    STD STD     0       0       0       0       0               8698230653923   0.00
```

**UPDATE :**

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(lblPath.Text);
var lines = text.Split('\n'); //Unix-based newline
var longestLine = lines.OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).First();
var shortestLine = lines.OrderBy(a => a.Length).First();
var orderByShort = lines.OrderBy(a => a.Length);
```

I get out of memory exception in this code.Above example is only a part of my file.My notepad file is 105 **MB**.

Comment: What Encoding does the file use? What encoding (if any) do you specify for the File instance? Show the actuall code, rather then images, including the code that opens the file. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: What you see in VS is the internal representation. Things like `\t` represent tab spacing and so on.

Comment: @Christopher UTF8

Comment: @derloopkat I try it open in my Vs and it shows like in my code how can this be possible :))

Comment: @AlicanKablan: As martin said in his answer, Notepad is not the best tool for opening Textfiles. It has maybe 4 Encoding options, most of wich are not even Unicode. So having it pick the "wrong" one is rather easy. Also, wich part was UTF-8? The file on disk? The Encoding for the File Opening?

Comment: @Christopher The Encoding for the File Opening.The creator of this notepad file doesnt know what is encoding he is only copying and pasting this lines in notepad and giving to my company.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here; "readline is not working right for my file" and "my code doesnt understand lines like this" aren't very descriptive.  Based on your sample input, `asdad2a[1]` should really be at the end of `asdad2a[0]`, not a separate element.  Are you sure there's not a `'\n'` between `DISCHY 8 BLUZ` and `std STD`?  TIP: Open the input file in Visual Studio and enable Edit > Advanced > View White Space.  TIP: Click the magnifying glass icon next to a `string` value in the debugger to display it in the Text Visualizer, with tabs and newlines rendered as whitespace.

Comment: The first line of the file is messed up.  It is messed up in the copy/paste into the SO posts as well, it is just that the formatting hides it.  There is an extra line-ending after BLUZ.  So it reads exactly how it is formatted, there is no bug.  You can trivially fix it with a text editor, but clearly you'll want to get in touch with the programmer that wrote the code to create this file to find out why this happened.  Post formatting fixed to make it obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.ReadAllText` to read the whole file to a `string` and then use the `Split` method to split based on the end of line character your file is using:

```
   var text = File.ReadAllText(myFilePath);
   var lines = text.Split("\n"); //Unix-based newline
```

`File.ReadAllLines` by default uses `\r\n` sequence for new lines - see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed.

Comment: It works and I understand now my problem.Thank you for answer.But now I have exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException' .

Comment: How big is your file? Could you post the updated code?